# Установил Pandas, а read_parquet(...) не работает без установки fastparquet или pyarrow

Tags: python, apache, pandas

Этот код:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet(
   'https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis/blob/master/plotly/data/medium_data_2019_01_06?raw=true',
    engine = 'fastparquet'
)
```

выдает ошибку:

```
......      
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'fastparquet'. fastparquet is required for parquet support. Use pip or conda to install fastparquet.
```

Собственно просьба проверить из под своего  Pandas.
Должно было бы работать. т.к. `conda upade pandas` выдавала что всё ок.
У меня не работало  и с `engine = 'pyarrow'` до дополнительной установки модуля `'pyarrow'` .  Я думаю, что установка Pandas должна была подтянуть все зависимые модули, поэтому спрашиваю )))

Comment: Не должна была.

Comment: @strawdog  в документации про это ни слова.
вот здесь https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/io.html#pickling
здесь и csv, и picle. Как узнать, что надо устанавливать, а что не надо, если особенно учесть, что  `engine ` - необязательный параметр?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При установке Pandas не устанавливаются *все* пакеты, которые могут понадобиться при работе с определенными методами / функциями. Например вы можете захотеть читать данные из MySQL DB. Установка соответствующего драйвера остается на вашей совести. Тоже самое происходит при работе с Parquet файлами - Pandas предоставляет обертки для работы с Parquet - `pd.read_parquet()` и `DataFrame.to_parquet()`. При этом можно использовать два независимых драйвера - `pyarrow` и `fastparquet`. Лично я предпочитаю `pyarrow`, т.к. один из его создателей - "отец" и создатель модуля Pandas - [Wes McKinney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wes_McKinney).

В Pandas существует очень удобная функция показывающая версии модулей, которые используются в Pandas - `pd.show_versions()`:

```
In [38]: pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit           : None
python           : 3.6.8.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Windows
OS-release       : 10
machine          : AMD64
processor        : Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : en_US.UTF-8
LANG             : en_US
LOCALE           : None.None

pandas           : 0.25.1
numpy            : 1.16.5
pytz             : 2019.3
dateutil         : 2.8.0
pip              : 19.2.3
setuptools       : 41.4.0
Cython           : 0.29.13
pytest           : 5.2.1
hypothesis       : None
sphinx           : 2.2.0
blosc            : None
feather          : None
xlsxwriter       : 1.2.1
lxml.etree       : 4.4.1
html5lib         : 1.0.1
pymysql          : None
psycopg2         : 2.7.6.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)
jinja2           : 2.10.3
IPython          : 7.8.0
pandas_datareader: None
bs4              : 4.8.0
bottleneck       : 1.2.1
fastparquet      : 0.3.0
gcsfs            : None
lxml.etree       : 4.4.1
matplotlib       : 3.1.1
numexpr          : 2.7.0
odfpy            : None
openpyxl         : 3.0.0
pandas_gbq       : None
pyarrow          : 0.13.0
pytables         : None
s3fs             : 0.3.4
scipy            : 1.3.1
sqlalchemy       : 1.3.9
tables           : 3.5.2
xarray           : None
xlrd             : 1.2.0
xlwt             : 1.3.0
xlsxwriter       : 1.2.1
```

Comment: мдя. а в документации ни слова про установку `pyarrow`. Честно говоря - не кажется это логичным, т.к. из коробки использование функции идет с установленным по умолчанию  `engine = 'auto' `. И первым ищется  `pyarrow`. 
так вот, почему при установке  `conda upade pandas ` все же не тянуть установку `pyarrow`,  ведь я вызываю параметр по умолчанию.
а не забыл вставить один из обязательных sql - серверов.
мне ж sqlite3 не надо в пайтон прикручивать.
или я нелогичен?

Comment: здесь:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/io.html#pickling   много всяких функций.  как узнать, к какой надо драйвер, а к какой не надо? там  и csv, и picle?   ведь например, df.to_json() работает без установки драйверов?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, `json` и `pickle` - модули из стандартной библиотеки - их не нужно устанавливать дополнительно. Я считаю, что разработчики Pandas сделали правильно. Как обычно 80% пользователей используют 20% возможностей и большинству пользователей никогда не понадобятся дополнительные модули. Зачем же тогда перегружать окружение ненужными драйверами?

Comment: я не критикую.  И да - правильно сделали 20 на 80.  Я к тому что в документации  Pandas должны были бы быть пояснения. Звездочка какая или еще что. 
Я ж этот код из вопроса скопировал из документации `plotly` как пример для обучения графике... И про ПАРКЕТ вообще ничего не знал...
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: ну написали бы: для работы нужно установить драйвер...
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html?highlight=read_parquet#pandas.read_parquet

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, ребята из Pandas Core Team с благодарностью принимают помощь в виде PR (Pull Requests) на GitHub. Если хотите можете дополнить документацию и оформить это как PR ;)

Comment: i did it ))))
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29689

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, под PR я подразумевал [это](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/contributing.html) ;)